# How to hide UINavigationBar while moving through controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have an app that needs clear navigationBar at first ViewController, and white navigationBar at second.

The problem is that when I'm moving between controllers (by UIBarButton), this terrible white stripe remains. What's wrong?

```
//for first ViewController to hide navigationBar, second is the same, but "true" and .white

  navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
  navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
  navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
  navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
```

[At first start it works fine, but when you return with button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqdAv.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both of your controllers in embedded in a single navigation controller with its own single navigation bar.

So when you change navigation bar color and style on the second controller and then go back to your first controller - these changes remain and so you see the white bar.

I would recommend you to hide the bar for the first controller and show it on the second one.
Or change its style (color, background image) every time inside `viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the first View controller navigation bar. Add modifications and changes in **AppDelegate** that you want to include from second view controller.In the first view controller hide navigation bar in **viewWillAppear** and show again in **viewWillDisappear**.

In First View Controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```